# Serializing Dictionary with JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary, serialization, dump

So I'm trying to JSON dump a dictionary created from a processed CSV in Python.

Method for creating dictionary:

```
def createUUIDDocIDLink(path):
   dict = defaultdict
   with open(path) as citTSV:
      header = 0
      for line in csv.reader(citTSV, dialect = "excel-tab"):
         if header > 0 and line[1] not in dict:
            dict[line[1]] = [line[0]]
         elif header > 0 and line[1] in dict:
            dict[line[1]].append(line[0])
      header += 1
   return dict
```

Method for dumping dictionary:

```
def dumpCreateUUIDDocIDLink():
   with open("D:/Coding/FE_InOut/dumpUUIDDocIDLookup",'w') as ULookup:
      output = json.dump(createUUIDDocIDLink("D:/Coding/FE_InOut/ipcr.tsv"),ULookup)
   return output
```

The error I'm receiving is:

"raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

TypeError: class 'collections.defaultdict' is not JSON serializable"

Where am I going wrong? Why can I not store this dict in memory? Does anybody have a workaround I could use?

Thanks a lot for your time & help,
Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: What makes you think something has gone wrong?

Comment: `json.dump` doesn't return anything, so assigning it to `output` and returning it is useless.

Comment: You need to indent the body of a function. I assume that's a copying error, not in the real code.

Comment: `json.dump()` stores the JSON in the file and returns nothing. If you want to store the JSON in memory, use `json.dumps()`.

Comment: @ScottHunter Please see the edited body for the error code, thanks for your response!

Comment: @Mikk Assigning to output may be redundant, but am I right in saying this isn't causing the defaultdict serialization problem?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you have to indent in stackoverflow to signify code, so I indent the first line when it isn't in my code. :)

Comment: @lel23 You should indent the whole block of code consistently. Mark the code and type Ctl-k or click on the `{}` icon in the toolbar.

Comment: @Barmar For these purposes storing in the file should be okay yes? I simply want to save this massive amount of data in the dictionary to file, so that when I'm developing later feature extraction parts of the program that process the dictionary, I don't have to create the dict every time.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the directions on indenting code in S.O. properly, noted for the future.

Comment: @lel23 I was just addressing your question "Why can I not store this dict in memory?" It was unclear whether you wanted to store the dict in memory or a file.

Comment: @Barmar Yep, sorry - as far as I'm aware file is good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
dict = defaultdict
```

is wrong. To declare a defaultdict containing a list you have to write:

```
dict = defaultdict(list)
```

But you don't need a deafultdict anyway, because you are taking care of the initialization yourself. I would also not use `dict` as variable name, so I'd just replace the line with:

```
mydict = {}
```

and make sure that all commands referring to `dict` now refer to `mydict`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mikk, I'll test our your suggestion now.

Comment: Hi, your suggestion worked straight away - thank you very much for your help

Comment: `defaultdicts` get serialized as normal `dict`s. The problem was that the *type* `defaultdict` is not serializable.